# android - How to handle all onTouch events in child and parent

Tags: android, android-event, android-touch-event

I hava `RecyclerView` with custom views, which handle `onTouch` event and do some work when `ACTION_UP` handled.
Also I want to get gestures and handle `onTouch` event in my root view. I need to handle full event: `ACTION_DOWN` ... `ACTION_UP` in both of my views.

But I have problem:

1. If I return `true` in my custom view, It handle other events and works OK, but `onTouch` event in my root view doesn't call.
2. If I return `false` in my custom view It handle just `ACTION_DOWN` and doesn't work, but my root view get all events and works OK.

So, **How can I handle all events both in child and root views?**

Comment: what are you using ACTION_DOWN/UP for? it sounds like you want an onItemClickListener . elaborate on what you're trying to achieve

Comment: This is my custom view which is Calendar. Month is drawing fully on canvas, arvery day, everything. I need to know, which date is clicked using it X and Y coord. This is from `CalendarScrallView` library and I haven't abilty to change it.

Comment: this won't work on all devices so easily. i would not use coordinates, but use a custom `Calendar` layout instead. it is a bit of hard work but worths it

Comment: There a lot of problems: I need to draw some specific icons, lines on my calednar and have it in two forms: normal calendar, vertical scrolling month and small horizontal calendar strip for only one week, horizontal scrall. There are much code which was hard to debug, but now it works good. 

I tried to use `mycustomview.dispatchTouchEvent`from root but It calls root's `onTouch` and it become a `recursy`

Comment: try to override `onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)`